# Flutter Visibility with Condition (How can I hide only one widget with condition)

Tags: flutter, dart, visibility

I have a problem with using Visibility widget.

What I want to do is hiding certain listview's by depending user's click on my Row. But when User click on row, all Listview is showing. When clicked again, all listview widget's are going away.

What I want to do is with images:
[This is how my page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj6oB.png)
[This is what happens when I click on arrow button or "Sezon 1" Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZjI8.png)
[This is what I want to do when I click on arrow button or "Sezon 1" Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWXkf.png)

What I'm trying to do is When I click Season 2, it will show season 2 episodes. When I click season 3 it will show season 3 episodes etc.

Here is my code (I know It's a little messy for right now, apologize for that) :
GestureDetector is working same for every click.

```
bool viewVisible = false;
void hideWidget() {
setState(() {
  viewVisible = !viewVisible;
  print(viewVisible);
});

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: seasons.snapshots(),
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
                  if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                        child:
                            Text('Error'));
                  } else {
                    if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                      List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocumentSnap =
                          asyncSnapshot.data.docs;

                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: listOfDocumentSnap.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  var episodes = firestore
                                      .collection('shows')
                                      .doc(data.id)
                                      .collection('Seasons')
                                      .doc(listOfDocumentSnap[index].id)
                                      .collection('Episodes');

                                  return Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 0, left: 18, right: 18),
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            hideWidget();
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(
                                                        8),
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                    color: Colors.pink)),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 20,
                                                ),
                                                Text(
                                                  listOfDocumentSnap[index]
                                                      .get('name')
                                                      .toString()
                                                      .toUpperCase(),
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 20,
                                                      color:
                                                          Colors.grey[800],
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w700),
                                                ),
                                                Spacer(flex: 1),
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                                  size: 45,
                                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                        stream: episodes.snapshots(),
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
                                          if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
                                            return Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                    'Error'));
                                          } else {
                                            if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                                              List<DocumentSnapshot>
                                                  listOfDocumentSnap =
                                                  asyncSnapshot.data.docs;

                                              return Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                        top: 5, left: 18.0),
                                                child: Visibility(
                                                  visible: viewVisible,
                                                  child: Align(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.topLeft,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        ListView.builder(
                                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                                          itemCount:
                                                              listOfDocumentSnap
                                                                  .length,
                                                          itemBuilder:
                                                              (context,
                                                                  index) {
                                                            return ListTile(
                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                setState(
                                                                    () {
                                                                  selectedIndex =
                                                                      index;
                                                                });
                                                              },
                                                              trailing:
                                                                  Icon(Icons
                                                                      .play_arrow),
                                                              title: Text(listOfDocumentSnap[
                                                                      index]
                                                                  .id
                                                                  .toString()),
                                                            );

                                                            /*   return Text(
                                                                listOfDocumentSnap[
                                                                        index]
                                                                    .get(
                                                                        'name'));*/
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            } else {
                                              return Center(
                                                  child:
                                                      CircularProgressIndicator());
                                            }
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 30,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I did not check what is wrong with your code. But, instead of writing your own hide/show logic for each row, try to use Flutter's ExpansionTile widget. It will handle the expanded/collapsed states for you:

https://medium.com/flutterdevs/expansion-tile-in-flutter-d2b7ba4a1f4b

[image: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/expansion-tile-in-flutter-d2b7ba4a1f4b]

Comment: Hello, I didnt know there is a widget for that. And it worked awesome! Thank you. (Teşekkürler :D)

Answer (score 3):

There are two different way I know to handle widget visibility. Create a bool to switch visibility. I'm using `_show`.

**Using if condition**
inside (column or any widget)

`if (_show) Container(),`

**Using Visibility Widget**

```
  Column(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: _show,
            child: Container(),
          ),
      )
```

Comment: Yeah I am using something like _show. But it closes every item instead of showing only one. I tried to use if (_show) Container(), but it doesnt accept if condition on before widget

Comment: Create separate statefullWidget for every `show`, or make a list of bool and use placing index like `show[0]`..

Comment: Yeah creating list of bool's worked too. I prefered using Expansion Tile widget, it is an awesome widget for this! But thank you for your answer aswell!